# How to properly implement GraphQL resolvers

Tags: database, go, graphql, typegraphql, gqlgen

I am creating a basic Graphql project. In this project I am only fetching user details. The data is stored in database. Here is the GQL schema:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  age: Int
  address : String
  firstname: String
  lastname :String
}

type Query {
  getUserById(id: ID!): User
}
```

When client queries my endpoint there will be 2 connection involved.

- **Connection 1**: From/to user to my resolver.
- **Connection 2** : From/to my resolver to my database.

Graphql will help me save bandwidth of **Connection 1** if I am not requesting some fields.

But, in **Connection 2** same amount data will be requested and fetched every time because the same sql query is running for ever request.

For example,

This query

```
query {
  getUserById(id: "your_user_id_here") {
    id
    username
    email
    age
  }
}
```

And this query

```
query {
  getUserById(id: "your_user_id_here") {
    id
    username
    email
    age
    address
    firstname
    lastname
  }
}
```

Both trigger the same resolver function in my backend which will run the same sql query( `select id, email, username.....`) for both the cases. So am I not saving any bandwidth in **Connection 2**  when data requested is less.  Right now my schema is small but as it will increase this becomes a much bigger problem.

The underlying libraries of my backend code will ensure only requested fields will be returned to the user. I ams using gqlgen and researched on TypeGraphQL. Both seems work the same in this regards.

My question is: am I missing some graphql concept or is this really a problem? If yes, any suggestions on how to improve my resolvers.

I researched but was not able to find any stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The important bandwidth to conserve is in *connection 1* as you've described it. Your GraphQL server should be *near* your database and connected via a high speed connection. This is typical for a 3-tier design.

As your schema gets more complex you'll end up with computed fields and related types which *will* get pruned (not executed) from the query plan if the client doesn't request those fields.

For example let's say that instead of storing `age` directly in the db (invariably a bad idea) you stored birth date instead (or at least birth year). Then `age` would be a computed field with its own resolver. If the client did not request `age` that resolver would not run.

Comment: Sounds fair, but as your schema gets more complex your tables in the database can also get more complex. This means that some tables can have a lot of columns added and making a `select * from "table"...` query all the time is a waste of resources and can add latency over time.

Comment: I didn't say anything about doing a select *…

Comment: Does this mean that, if my tables are small this is not much of an issue?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really good.

I don't know what framework you are using. But in Go + gqlgen, we can avoid the select * sometimes. Sometimes is not worth implementing a resolver for each column.

In node, I used to use Nexus and Prisma. It's a big problem because the framework always fetches the whole table sometimes.

Probably it's fine to always select multiple columns for most cases. If this becomes a problem you should have a workaround available for your preferred framework using custom fields or a resolver for each column.